# Extract ipv6 prefix in python

Tags: python, ipv6

Given either the binary or string representation of an IPv6 address and its prefix length, what's the best way to extract the prefix in Python?

Is there a library that would do this for me, or would I have to:

1. convert the address from string to an int (inet_ntop)
2. Mask out the prefix
3. Convert prefix back to binary
4. Convert binary to string (inet_ntop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/ipaddr-py/

With this, you can do

```
py> p=ipaddr.IPv6("2001:888:2000:d::a2")
py> p.SetPrefix(64)
py> p
IPv6('2001:888:2000:d::a2/64')
py> p.network_ext
'2001:888:2000:d::'
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using the python [netaddr](https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr) library:

```
>>> from netaddr.ip import IPNetwork, IPAddress
>>> IPNetwork('2001:888:2000:d::a2/64').network
2001:888:2000:d::
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a small own function which extracts the IPv6 prefix:

```
# Returns the IPv6 prefix
def getIPv6Prefix(ipv6Addr, prefixLen):
    prefix = ""
    curPrefixLen = 0
    ipv6Parts = ipv6Addr.split(":")
    for part in ipv6Parts:
        if not prefix == "": # if it's not empty
            prefix = prefix + ":"
        prefix = prefix + part
        curPrefixLen += 32
        if int(curPrefixLen) >= int(prefixLen):
            return prefix
    return prefix
```